# Forward declaring a protocol in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My class .h looks like:

```
@protocol AppInfoDelegate;
@class InfoTextView;


@interface AppInfoViewController : UIViewController <AppInfoDelegate> {

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *textObjectsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) InfoTextView *itView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *pgBackButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *pgFwdButton;

@end

@protocol AppInfoDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

I get a warning that the protocol definition for AppInfoDelegate cannot be found.  What is the proper way to do this and why cannot it not be found?  Do I need to have the whole definition of the protocol before the interface?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `@protocol MyProtocol;` is useful when you are asserting, for example, that a method will take `id <MyProtocol>` as an argument.

It is *not* useful when you are claiming that your class conforms to `<MyProtocol>`. The reason for this is that the compiler needs the full protocol declaration in order to verify that your class *actually* conforms to the protocol.  (This compile-time check is one great reason to use formal protocols instead of the older informal ones.)

You can fix in two ways.  One, as @skram suggests, is to just forward-declare the whole thing.  This works, but it's also rather limited in my view.  Why bother with a protocol in that case - just put everything in the class `@interface` and be done with it.

The second approach, which I prefer, is to actually have a separate header, such as `MyProtocol.h`.  You can then freely import this into any header or implementation files as needed.  This allows you to reuse a protocol easily (and avoid the headaches of circular imports that sometimes arise).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@protocol AppInfoDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end   

@class InfoTextView;


@interface AppInfoViewController : UIViewController <AppInfoDelegate> {

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *textObjectsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) InfoTextView *itView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *pgBackButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *pgFwdButton;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, superclass and adopted protocol definitions need to be defined (verbatim or by using #import) before the class definition. They cannot be forward-declared.

Answer (score -1):

I've always seen the whole protocol definition before the @interface. I believe you can also put it into a separate file though