# how to solve 2 protocols which both of them have a reference to other one

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I am trying to create several protocols, and most of them have references to other ones. But I get error during the build process.

I give an example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DataChildDelegate <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic) id<DataParentDelegate> parent;

@end

@protocol DataParentDelegate <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic) id<DataChildDelegate> firstChild;
@property(nonatomic) id<DataChildDelegate> lastChild;

@end
```

I tried to divide **DataChildDelegate** in two parts like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DataChildDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@protocol DataParentDelegate <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic) id<DataChildDelegate> firstChild;
@property(nonatomic) id<DataChildDelegate> lastChild;

@end

@protocol DataChildDelegate <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic) id<DataParentDelegate> parent;

@end
```

But this time I get a warning.

Is there any more suitable way to handle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a forward declaration of the protocol `DataChildDelegate` prior to `DataParentDelegate` so that the compiler can trust that it exists.

For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DataChildDelegate;     /*Forward declaration of DataChildDelegate */

@protocol DataParentDelegate <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic) id<DataChildDelegate> firstChild;
@property(nonatomic) id<DataChildDelegate> lastChild;

@end

@protocol DataChildDelegate <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic) id<DataParentDelegate> parent;

@end
```

Comment: FYI: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11532888/758831 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11091897/758831 for more specifics on the use of forward declarations.