# 'SWIFT_NORETURN' macro redefined

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14, xcode12.5

On Xcode 12.5 I get this when I try to compile my test target:

```
/Users/user/Development/project-ios/My ProjectTests/My ProjectTests-Bridging-Header.h:7:9: note: in file included from /Users/user/Development/project-ios/My ProjectTests/My ProjectTests-Bridging-Header.h:7:
#import "SpecHelper.h"
        ^
/Users/user/Development/project-ios/My ProjectTests/SpecHelper.h:36:9: note: in file included from /Users/user/Development/project-ios/My ProjectTests/SpecHelper.h:36:
#import "My_Project-Swift.h"
        ^
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My._Project-eybfcywypdtewfbihzpxuwyltrxw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/My Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My Project.build/DerivedSources/My_Project-Swift.h:98:10: error: 'SWIFT_NORETURN' macro redefined
# define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/shims/Visibility.h:86:9: note: previous definition is here
#define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((__noreturn__))
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/user/Development/project-ios/My ProjectTests/My ProjectTests-Bridging-Header.h'
Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Project-Swift.h

```
#if __has_attribute(noreturn)
# define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
# define SWIFT_NORETURN
#endif
```

and Visibility.h

```
#if __has_attribute(noreturn)
#define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((__noreturn__))
#else
#define SWIFT_NORETURN
#endif
```

Note: this works on Xcode 12.4.

Any idea how to work around this?

UPDATE (May 27th): If I delete the derived data, run the test suite it fails with the error described above. Trying to run it the second time seems to work. I have no idea why that is the case.

UPDATE 2: (June 3rd): The problem seems to be that I have a class defined in a .h file that conforms to a protocol defined in a swift file, different targets. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091897/429763) explains why I cannot use forward declaration so I don't have to import the "MyProject-Swift.h" file.

Comment: Did you try removing the re-definition?

Comment: See below @EmilioPelaez, I am not adding the definition myself, instead one is generated into the "My-Project.swift" file, and the other one seems to be a "shim" in the simulator's "../shims/Visibility.h" file. I won't be able to change those I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately clear to me why you're declaring the macro in different places, but there must be a circular import or something where it ends up getting redefined.

Option 1 is refactor the code so that you only declare that macro in one spot and then import it from the necessary locations.

Option 2 is to wrap each declaration so that it doesn't get redefined:

```
#ifndef SWIFT_NORETURN

#if __has_attribute(noreturn)
#define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((__noreturn__))
#else
#define SWIFT_NORETURN
#endif

#endif
```

Or:

```
#if __has_attribute(noreturn) && !defined(SWIFT_NORETURN)
#define SWIFT_NORETURN __attribute__((__noreturn__))
#else
#define SWIFT_NORETURN
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, I think it happens to be a circular import involved, but I am not declaring it explicitly, which means I won't be able to check for the existence of it. The project target is imported in the `SpecHelper.h` file: "#import "My_Project-Swift.h" and that ends up conflicting with the one defined in the `Visibility.h`.
I won't be able to the change either of those I presume.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check, that your header files does not include line `#import "Project-Swift.h"`. Ideally, only `*.m` files should include this generated header.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ZGI6YXNt . I think my problem is that I have a class in a .h file that conforms to a protocol defined in a swift file, different targets. I was trying to go around this problem by forward declaring the protocol, but I think it's not possible as conformance needs to be verified by the compiler and for that it needs the whole declaration. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091897/429763

Comment: There are several different ways to solve this problem, for example, you can rewrite this class entirely in swift, or only the part that is responsible for the conformance to the protocol. There are also other options if these are not suitable for some reason.